# How to process data with multiindex using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, feature-extraction

I have a Series like this.

[image]

I want to process this Series to get the max `p` for each ip.

Result:

`ip
192.168.1.1     22
192.168.1.2      4
192.168.1.3      3
192.168.1.4      4`

Is there any way to do this easily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `ip` is in the index (in the first position) you should use this syntax.

```
s.groupby(level=0).max()

# ip
# 192.168.1.1    22
# 192.168.1.2     4
# 192.168.1.3     3
# 192.168.1.4     4
# Name: p, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the [pandas groupby clause](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.Series.groupby.html#pandas.Series.groupby): `s.groupby(level=0).max()`

**Example:**

```
iterables = [['192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.2', '192.168.1.3', '192.168.1.4'],
             ['123455', '123456', '123457']]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables, names=['ip', 'p'])
s = pd.Series(np.random.randint(30, size=12), index=index)
s
```

Output:

```
ip           p     

192.168.1.1  123455    18
             123456    20
             123457    12
192.168.1.2  123455    25
             123456     1
             123457     4
192.168.1.3  123455    28
             123456    19
             123457    22
192.168.1.4  123455    20
             123456    10
             123457    12
```

And to get the max for each IP:

```
s.groupby(level=0).max()
```

Output:

```
ip
192.168.1.1    20
192.168.1.2    25
192.168.1.3    28
192.168.1.4    20
```

**Edit:**
Changed from `s.groupby['ip'].max()` to `s.groupby(level=0).max()` as some tests I made were not working